# angularjs: how to set scroll position

Tags: angularjs, scrollbar

I have a div element with the `overflow-x` style attribute set to `scroll .

I want to be able to set the scrollbar position by code. With jQuery I'd use the `scrollRight()` function.

What'd be the best approach with angular ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should keep your JQ code for that and run it in the link function of your directive.

Comment: it sounds like the most sensitive thing to do :) thanks*